# Is it possible to delete your entire Stack Overflow favourites list in one fell swoop?

Tags: support, bookmarks

This question is a little bit challenging to find an answer to in search engines...

My SO 'favourites' list has got so large over the years that I don't bother using it much anymore to find older posts I want to revisit (using web browser bookmarks instead).

Obviously one can unclick favourites manually ... but what if it's many pages++ long and clicking one by one feels like a mentally excruciating experience?

Does a quick and easy way to delete all my favourite marked posts exist, so I can start again from scratch and only selectively save questions of interest going forward?

Comment: Maybe it’s possible to crawl the fav list and call `POST https://stackoverflow.com/posts/{id}/vote/5?undo=true` on all of them.

Comment: But... you're already using the far superior method of saving interesting questions - bookmarks. Just forget the favorites function exists.

Comment: Before you move forward on you quest to purge your favorites, did you know that you can limit a search to your favorites via `infavorites:mine` or `infavorites:1717729`? For example, to [search within your favorites](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=infavorites%3A1717729+%5Br-faq%5D) for questions tagged `[r-faq]`. I consider my numerous collection of favorites to be my own personal corner of SO and use this focused search capability frequently to limit my search results to Q&A I have previously found particularly helpful.

Comment: @DavidRR ... the favorites just got a little bit more useful, thanks for sharing that.

Comment: @DavidRR +1 Thanks for the reminder. I have read about this option to search favourites before, but I guess 'my corner of SO' is so large with many favourites that are no longer relevant to me anymore (favourites are from years ago) ... but you make a good point

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For a client-side solution, here's a userscript which will remove all of your favorites - just install it with something like [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo), go to your profile's favorites tab, e.g.,

```
https://stackoverflow.com/users/9515207/certainperformance?tab=favorites
```

and it'll do the work from there, ending once all favorites and pages have been iterated through and removed:

```javascript
// ==UserScript==
// @name             Stack Remove Favorites
// @author           CertainPerformance
// @include          /^https?://stackoverflow\.com/users/\d+/.+\?.*tab=(bookmarks|favorites).*$/
// @grant            none
// ==/UserScript==

const RATE_LIMIT = 1000;

const delay = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));

const unfavorite = (questionId) => (
  fetch(
    `https://stackoverflow.com/posts/${questionId}/vote/5?undo=true`,
    {
      method: 'POST',
      credentials: 'same-origin',
      headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
      },
      body: `fkey=${StackExchange.options.user.fkey}`
    }
  )
  .then(res => res.json())
);

const getFavoriteQuestionIds = () => Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(
  '#user-tab-bookmarks .s-post-summary--content-title.s-link'
)).map(x => x.href.match(/\d+/)[0]);

const removeFavoritesAndRefreshPage = async () => {
  const favs = getFavoriteQuestionIds();

  if (favs.length === 0)
    return;

  for (let i = 0; i < favs.length; i++) {
    const questionId = favs[i];
    console.log(`Unfavoriting ${questionId}...`)
    await unfavorite(questionId);
    await delay(RATE_LIMIT);
  };

  // Refresh page.
  window.location.href = window.location.href;
};


setTimeout(removeFavoritesAndRefreshPage, RATE_LIMIT);
```

(Remember to disable or uninstall it afterwards if you want to be able to continue using favorites.)

Comment: What web browsers is this supposed to work in? All [the official ones supported by Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need/71208#71208)?

Comment: It should work in any browser that's reasonably up-to-date, the `async` keyword is from [ES2017](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: You can replace `stackoverflow.com` with `${window.location.host}` so it works automatically for every site.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for Chrome for the current StackOverflow site.