# How to remove old bookmarks?

Tags: support, bookmarks

After being active for a few years on Stack Overflow, my number of bookmarks is nearing 2000. And that's not particularly useful. Is there a way to "uncheck" bookmarks that are, for example, more than 3 years old?

Comment: The Stack Exchange API has an [Unbookmarks a question](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/undo-favorite-question). You'll need a key and a client secret to make use of it. You can register for that on [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com) by pressing the "Register an application". Note: you'll have to create a placeholder post first. For finding which ones you want to remove, there's [questions bookmarked](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me-favorites)

Comment: I noticed there's also a "Get token" directly on the API documentation. I've never tried to use it, so I have no idea how that works.

Comment: @Scratte it works as advertised unless you are stuck on [IE 11](https://stackapps.com/questions/4581/get-token-button-in-try-it-doesnt-give-me-a-key-in-ie11) ....

Comment: "Can this be fixed so it works for all supported browsers?". Yes. IE11 is no longer supported ;)

Comment: Take this as a starting point: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381968/is-it-possible-to-delete-your-entire-stack-overflow-favourites-list-in-one-fell/381996#381996 and then you can filter by date, should be a simple tweak

Comment: *"Stack Overflow is a forum"* (paraphrased) from a 33,000 reputation points user and [from the CEO](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uPbbt7Dg-2U&t=2m57s). ***[Stack Overflow is](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92115) [\*\*\*\*\*\*NOT\*\*\*\*\*\* a forum](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/36828)***. Where have we failed? Why is it so difficult to understand (not a rhetorical question)?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Thanks for the read (added to bookmarks =). But I don't think you'll get quite the attention you seem to be seeking in a comment to question with 55 views. Feel free to raise `Where have we failed? ` as a new question with links to this post (I'll leave it unedited). If anything, I doubt it's going to be ******NOT****** interesting.

Comment: @PeterMortensen I think that has a lot to do with the fact that, to date, we ***still*** don't have a good, succinct, alternative term for what Stack Overflow is, other than the constantly parroted "*not a forum*" phrase. Stack should trademark that at this point.

Comment: @zcoop98 Ummm, yes we do, it's a Q&A site

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to "uncheck" bookmarks that are, for example, more than 3 years old?

Yes.

1. Go to your bookmarks page on your profile's Activity tab
2. Sort by either "Newest" or "Added" (depending on what you mean by "*more than 3 years old*")
3. Go to the last page of your bookmarks results
4. Click the bookmark icon next to each question you want to un-bookmark:

   [image: bookmark icon]

If you hover over the bookmark icon, you'll note the cursor turns into a pointer and a tooltip appears that reads:

> You have bookmarked this question (**click to undo**)

(emphasis mine)

There is no automated way to remove a chunk of bookmarks, however.

Comment: Thank you for answering! I should perhaps have been more specifc, but I was indeed looking for a way to do this for larger chunks of bookmarks in one go.

Comment: @vestland In that case a custom solution like this one is probably your best bet: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381968/is-it-possible-to-delete-your-entire-stack-overflow-favourites-list-in-one-fell